# ASP Code In .SHTML Page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, asp-classic, vbscript

I'm managing an ASP 2.0 site that I didn't create running under IIS7.

I would like to put a single line of VB code in several `.shtml` files.

I tried doing something like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        Today is <%= Date() %>
    </body>
</html>
```

But it actually renders:

```
<html>
    <body>
        Today is <%= Date() %>
    </body>
</html>
```

instead of the expected:

```
<html>
    <body>
        Today is 7/2/2012
    </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I run VB code in a `.shtml` file running under ASP 2.0 / IIS 7 ?

(No javascript, thanks)

Comment: My guess would be that IIS is not configured to process .shtml files through .NET

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIS > Sites > MySite > Handler Mappings

Select record with path of *.shtml > Edit > IsapiModule